# Uploading an Image from an external link to google cloud storage using google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for a solution on how to upload a picture from an external url like `http://example.com/image.jpg` to google cloud storage using appengine python,

I am now using

```
blobstore.create_upload_url('/uploadSuccess', gs_bucket_name=bucketPath)
```

for users that want to upload a picture from their computer, calling

```
images.get_serving_url(gsk,size=180,crop=True)
```

on uploadSuccess and storing that as their profile image. I'm trying to allow users to use their facebook or google profile picture after they login with oauth2. I have access to their profile picture link, and I would just like to copy it for consistency. Pease help :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To upload an external image you have to get it and save it.
To get the image you van use [this code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/):

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

file_name = 'image.jpg'
url = 'http://example.com/%s' % file_name
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
    doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

To save the image you can use the app engine GCS client code [shown here](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133)

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
import mimetypes

doSomethingWithResult(content):

    gcs_file_name = '/%s/%s' % ('bucket_name', file_name)
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0]
    with gcs.open(gcs_file_name, 'w', content_type=content_type,
                  options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read'}) as f:
        f.write(content)

    return images.get_serving_url(blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + gcs_file_name))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer is awesome. works like a charm and it;s very comprehensive. @voscausa rocks! I would vote your answer up but i don't have the rep :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my *new solution (2019)* using the `google-cloud-storage` library and `upload_from_string()` function only (see [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html)):

```
from google.cloud import storage
import urllib.request

BUCKET_NAME = "[project_name].appspot.com" # change project_name placeholder to your preferences
BUCKET_FILE_PATH = "path/to/your/images" # change this path

def upload_image_from_url_to_google_storage(img_url, img_name):
    """
    Uploads an image from a URL source to google storage.
    - img_url: string URL of the image, e.g. https://picsum.photos/200/200
    - img_name: string name of the image file to be stored
    """
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    blob = bucket.blob(BUCKET_FILE_PATH + "/" + img_name + ".jpg")

    # try to read the image URL
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(img_url) as response:
            # check if URL contains an image
            info = response.info()
            if(info.get_content_type().startswith("image")):
                blob.upload_from_string(response.read(), content_type=info.get_content_type())
                print("Uploaded image from: " + img_url)
            else:
                print("Could not upload image. No image data type in URL")
    except Exception:
        print('Could not upload image. Generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an updated way of doing this relying on `storages` package, I wrote those 2 functions:

```
import requests
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage


def download_file(file_url, file_name):
    response = requests.get(file_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        upload_to_gc(response.content, file_name)


def upload_to_gc(content, file_name):
    gc_file_name = "{}/{}".format("some_container_name_here", file_name)
    with GoogleCloudStorage().open(name=gc_file_name, mode='w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Then normally call `download_file()` and pass `url` and `prefered_file_name` from anywhere within your system.

The class `GoogleCloudStorage` came from `django-storages` package.

`pip install django-storages`

[Django Storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Hey! where comes this `GoogleCloudStorage` module from? it is not obtain via the usual `google-cloud-storage` package?

Comment: @TimoWagner It's coming from `storages` package. via `pip install django-storages
`

Comment: Thx Ramy for clarification... I posted another solution using the `google-cloud-storage` library. In case you don't want/need the django one (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556528/7810379))